# Why when using promise a correct value is returned while using async/await returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to understand why 2 snippets bellow return a different value. As my understanding the async/await version should return a promise with a found value inside. Spent the whole day trying to understand why it is not happening. Any help would be highly appreciated

using Promise return the value I expect

```
async function search(searchFor) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        machinery.run({
            eachItem: async (item) => {
                if (item.someValue===searchFor) {
                    return resolve(item);
                }
            }
        })
    })
}
```

using async/await returns undefined

```
async function search(searchFor) {
    return await machinery.run({
        eachItem: async (item) => {
            if (item.someValue===searchFor) {
                return item;
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: machinery.run should return a promise for async/await

Comment: Probably because `eachItem()` is not async-aware so it isn't feeding anything back to the caller.  If a method does not do anything with the promise that your `async` callback returns, then that promise and it's value is just lost.